# Executing default immediately

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using jQuery. My code is:

```
$("#input").keypress(function(event) {
  getConversion();
});
```

How do I let the keypressed be added to #input before calling getConversion()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do `keyup()`

```
$("#input").keyup(function(event) {
```

Comment: Is that really fired after keypress?  And, is that behavior guaranteed to be consistent from browser to browser?

Answer (score 0):

Change keypress to keyup:

```
$("#input").on("keyup", function() {
   getConversion();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is this:

```
$("#input").keypress(function(event) {
  setTimeout(getConversion, 1);
});
```

This will call `getConversion()` after the current event flow is done and this should work with auto-repeat inserted keys which will not work properly if you only listen for the keyup event.